# How can I change in phpgrid a column per programm

Tags: phpgrid

I add a virtual Column to phpgrid. How can I change the position of this column manually from the end to the second postion of the grid, The first columns are all filled by database?

```
$dg -> add_column('Brille',array('name'=>'Brille', 'index'=>'Brille', 'width'=>'30',),'Brille',0);
```

Any solution?

Every way I do is not working